# How to login using by specific id or variables from database table

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, session

Hye, I faced a problem where I need to create a log in that can only be access by specific id from my database table. how can I solve the problem where I just need to login by using admin_id = 1 for example, and there are no other user can login except this one id only because I put the admin and user login data inside of the same login tables. Help me solve this problem. Here my coding in php scripts. Thank you for helping.

```html
<?php
 if(ISSET ($_POST['login'])){
  $faculty_department = $_POST['faculty_department'];
  $password = $_POST['password'];
  $query = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM `user` WHERE `faculty_department` = '$faculty_department' && `password` = '$password'") or die(mysqli_error());
  $fetch = $query->fetch_array();
  $row = $query->num_rows;
  
  if($row > 0){
   session_start();
   $_SESSION['admin_id'] = $fetch['admin_id'];
   header('location:home1.php');
  }else{
   echo "<center><labe style = 'color:red;'>Invalid faculty_department or password</label></center>";
  }
 }
?>
```

Comment: hope you know, that you must escape your variables in the sql statment. Best option is to use [prepared statments](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Just add a `WHERE` condition to allow only admin access, assuming `admin_id` is 1

```
SELECT * FROM `user`
WHERE `faculty_department` = '$faculty_department'
AND `password` = '$password'
AND `admin_id` = '1'
```

Comment: Please explain the down vote. I'm ready to improve or delete the answer.